# Login Observer - Get Address after Registration Redirect

Tags: event-observer

I have an observer set up for customer login, and it is firing exactly as I need it to.  I need to have access to the customer's default shipping address within the observer, which I load via:

```
$defaultShipping = $customer->getPrimaryShippingAddress( );
```

This works fine, except when the user first registers; the `$defaultShipping` is null (I am assuming at this point is because the address itself hasn't been saved yet).  I have tried to overcome this by explicitly saving both the customer as well as all of the customer's addresses if `$defaultShipping` is `null`:

```
if( !$defaultShipping ) {
    $customer->save( );
    foreach( $customer->getAddresses( ) as $address ) {
        // Explicitly save each address (at this point there should only be one,
        // but looping just to be safe).  This should guarantee an ID for it 
        // exists
         $address->save( );
    }

    $defaultShipping = $customer->getPrimaryShippingAddress( );
}
```

This however is still giving `null` for `$defaultShipping`.  Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to load the default shipping address? Does the customer not get a default shipping address if they *just* registered (should I instead just choose an address from the collection if `$defaultShipping` is initially `null`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was a bit off.  The default shipping is not actually set for newly created customers; the addresses themselves are already saved, as can be demonstrated here (within the same observer method):

```
foreach( $customer->getAddresses( ) as $address ) {
     echo $address->getId( );
}
die;
```

To fix my issue, if the `$defaultShipping` value was null I simply took the first address out of the customer address collection as my 'default shipping' to use.  If anyone has any better solution, feel free to share.